# How to test the request executed by a rest client in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus-rest-client

I defined a simple interface to an external Rest service.

```
import io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.ClientQueryParam;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestQuery;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Path("/api")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "external-api")
@ClientQueryParam(name = "apikey", value = "${external-api.apikey}") // get value from properties
@ClientQueryParam(name = "format", value = "json") // always use json format
public interface ExternalService {

    enum PER {
        QUARTERLY,
        HOURLY,
        DAILY,
        WEEKLY,
        MONTHLY,
        YEARLY
    }

    /**
     * Uri format: /api/rest?apikey={{API_KEY}}&format=json&begin=2023-05-18&end=2023-05-18&per=quarterly&dap=11167
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/rest")
    Uni<String> getRest(
            @RestQuery("begin") @DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate fromDate,
            @RestQuery("end") @DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate toDate,
            @QueryParam("per") @StringFormat(toLowerCase = true) PER per,
            @QueryParam("dap") Integer connectionId);
}
```

To properly format some query parameters I created some annotations (DateFormat, StringFormat) with implementations of `ParamConverterProvider` and `ParamConverter<T>` to properly convert types into a String.

I have a Test for testing this client against a Wiremock stub, so the client works.

But how can I somehow verify the actual request send to the external service to verify the query parameters are indeed properly formatted?
Or when sending a payload, that the payload is properly formatted?

Comment: Hi, I guess you already found your solution but for the next time I recommend you read the next guides: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive and
https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive
and take a look at the quickstart repository where you will find the code examples : 
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts